# Не могу понять почему не работает программа на платформе stepik

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сама задача:

> Даны четыре действительных числа: x1, y1, x2, y2. Напишите функцию
> distance(x1, y1, x2, y2), вычисляющая расстояние между точкой (x1,y1)
> и (x2,y2). Считайте четыре действительных числа и выведите результат
> работы этой функции.
>
> Вывод с точность до 4-х знаков после запятой.

Код:

```
from math import sqrt
 
def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2)
 
x1 = float(input())
x2 = float(input())
y1 = float(input())
y2 = float(input())
print(distance(x1, x2, y1, y2)*100000 // 10 / 10000)
```

Comment: Во-первых, неправильный порядок ввода чисел. Во-вторых, неправильное округление

Answer (score 0):

Порядок считывания должен быть: `x1, y1, x2, y2`, в функцию вы тоже неправильно передаете параметры, там ведь сначала `x1`, после `x2`.

Выражение с `*100000 // 10 / 10000` странное, чтобы вывести с указанной точностью нужно результат функции `distance` привести к строке через форматирование, указав точность (`.4f`)

```
x1 = float(input())
y1 = float(input())
x2 = float(input())
y2 = float(input())
d = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)
print(f'{d:.4f}')
```

Если на той платформе будут проблемы с f-строками, то можно через функцию `format`:

```
print('{:.4f}'.format(d))
```